# What is the difference between a Random Vector (Joint r.v.) and a Random Process?

Tags: terminology, stochastic-processes

What is the difference between a Random Vector (Joint r.v.) and a Random Process?

Kindly, explain with a simple example (like toss of a coin, roll of a die, picking a card, etc.).

**Note.** As far as I understand, random process is a collection of equally spaced and indexed (generally, by time) random variables.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Give an example of a Random Vector](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/370690/give-an-example-of-a-random-vector)

Comment: The duplicate link is broken. Maybe check this out: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/569951/what-is-the-difference-between-a-random-vector-and-a-stochastic-process

Comment: The target of the duplicate link exists but is visible only to those with the reputation to see deleted posts.  It is, however, a duplicate of a (currently) undeleted post on Mathematics: see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2946642/give-an-example-of-a-random-vector.

Answer (score 0):

A random vector is a special case of a random process, where a random vector has discrete indexing (natural numbers) while a random process can be sampled everywhere and return a random variable. Actually, it's more common to say *stochastic* process instead of *random* process.

Comment: You describe a narrow sense of random process, one in "continuous time" (or space).  Although it is mathematically correct--and insightful--to point out that a random vector is a special case, that doesn't seem to capture what is special about the study and application of random processes in statistics.  Statistics exploits *additional structure* (such as temporal sequence or spatial proximity) to formulate models of interdependency among the values of the stochastic process.

Comment: I would add to this that a random vector arises as a result of sampling a random process at a single value of the parameter (continuous; time or space) or index (when discretized). The natural numbering is immaterial, as a random.vector arises at any real (not necessarily positive integer) sample valu of the time or space parameter. Also, "stochastic process" is typically used for a one--dimensional random process (e.g., with time as index), while "random field" usually refers to a multi-dimensional one (e.g., spatial process)..